# sed not replacing everything

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to remove all the spaces following / preceding single quotes from a datafile. However I'm not catching everything with the below scenario.

Input

```
{'_id':' BE3523 ', 'time':' 18:20 ', 'number':' BE3523 ', 'destination':' Bordeaux ', 'status': ' Scheduled '}
```

sed command I'm running...

```
sed -i.bak 's/['\'' ]\{2\}/'\''/g' input.json
```

Output

```
{'_id':'BE3523','time':'18:20','number':'BE3523','destination':'Bordeaux','status':' Scheduled'}
```

Note the space between `'_Scheduled` remains, but **every** other space has been removed. I have to run the sed command again to get rid of this final space for the below to be

```
{'_id':'BE3523','time':'18:20','number':'BE3523','destination':'Bordeaux','status':'Scheduled'}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and why this one space consistently remains?

Comment: `, ' Scheduled` has 3 characters of that character class, not 2.

Comment: please beware that using regex over structured data is usually a bad idea. Most of the times it's better to parse it, and then create the appropriate output. (think of cases where a \' is escaped inside the values, for example)

Comment: perl 5 alternative: `perl -i.bak -pe 's/[ ]+(?='\'')|(?<='\'')[ ]+//g' input.json`

Comment: Thanks LukStorms! Nailed it, was staring right at me. Changed {2} to {2,3}.

Comment: Davide you're quite right though I'm generating this JSON input from html pulled from a website as a temporary solution for a proof of concept whilst I get proper access to the underlying data. So I'm still forming the structured data at this stage and there will never be an escaped character in the data.

Comment: @NickS, I see you keep thinking you're having a valid JSON there, but you are not. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your input file, `input.json`, is not a valid [JSON](http://json.org/), since strings use single quotes, instead of double quotes.

Secondly, your `sed` expression is doing more than you (maybe) expect (and at the same time less): it will replace not only `'` (space, quote) or `'` (quote, space) with `'`, but also `''` (quote, quote) or  (space, space) with `'`. The reason is you're not using a specific sequence (as proposed by the other answer), or an exclusive or between `'` and  (quote and space).

To achieve the "compression" effect, which (I'm guessing) you're going for: removing multiple whitespace characters before **or** after a single quote, you could use this:

```
sed "s/[[:space:]]*'[[:space:]]*/'/g" file
```

To strip only spaces (not including newlines/tabs):

```
sed "s/ *' */'/g" file
```

On your sample input, both will produce:

```
{'_id':'BE3523','time':'18:20','number':'BE3523','destination':'Bordeaux','status':'Scheduled'}
```

I'm not sure why you would want to modify values by stripping leading/trailing spaces this way, though.

Comment: Sold! Taking your clear all spaces approach, thanks. The extra spaces are messing me up further downstream. The JSON file is of my own generation from HTML input, I just got lazy with the syntax. It's on my to do list to fix.

Comment: All you have to do to make it a valid JSON (for the sample input) is to  change `'` to `"` for string values. Then you'll be able to use JSON parsers, starting with `jq` for command-line usage.

Comment: At the moment I put it straight into MongoDB from here then do further modifications in there. But will explore the jq commands you mentioned

Comment: Got it. Unlike JSON, JavaScript (and MongoDB) accept strings with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace all the cases with a single quote, like this

```
sed -i.bak "s/\( ' \|' \| '\)/'/g"  input.json
```

Comment: Technically you're right and I was doing that before, but I was looking for a slightly cleaner method. Thanks!